# Sort array of objects by their numerical keys

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array, where its objects consist of a dynamic key of type number.

Now I want to sort the objects so that the numbers start from the smallest first -- the number I mean is the key of the object.

Here's my code

```js
const arr = [{"3": 32}, {"1": 42}, {"5": 48}];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

The order of the objects should be:

```
[{"1": 42},{"3":32},{"5":48}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: @Sheri No, that question is about sorting an array of objects by the _value_ of a fixed property, _lexicographically_. This question is about sorting an array of single-property objects by _key_, _numerically_.

Comment: Duplicate target found on [this search page](/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=is%3aa%20sort%20url%3a%22Object%2fkeys%22).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to extract the keys... like with `Object.keys`:

```js
const arr = [{"3": 32}, {"1": 42}, {"5": 48}];

arr.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this and it should work

```
let arr = [{"3": 32}, {"1": 42}, {"5": 48}];

let getKey=(array)=> Object.keys(array)[0]

arr.sort((a,b) => (getKey(a) - getKey(b)))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
const arr = [{"3": 32}, {"1": 42}, {"5": 48}];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  const firstKey = Object.keys(a)[0]
  const secondKey = Object.keys(b)[0]
    return  secondKey - firstKey
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether its perfect, but surely works.

```js
const arr = [{"3": 32}, {"1": 42}, {"5": 48}];

const sortedArr = arr.sort((a,b) => {
  let aKey = parseInt(Object.keys(a)[0]);
  let bKey = parseInt(Object.keys(b)[0]);

  return aKey - bKey;
});

console.log(sortedArr);
```